# PHP Array Selecting values that match certain criteria

Tags: php, arrays

If my array is formatted like this:

```
Array ( 
       [0] => Array ( 
                     [0] => Informatics [TitleName] => Informatics 
                     [1] => Informatics [TitleValue] => Informatics 
                     [2] => 1 [CategoryID] => 1 
                     [3] => [SecondaryCategory] => 
                     ) 
         )
```

How do I pull out all the values that are CategoryID == 1 ?

Ive tried several while loops but it does not seem to be working properly. Can Anyone help me out with this? Perhaps a while loop is not what I need.

Comment: You can do it with a while loop, but I suspect someone is going to answer with a built-in php function.  Something along the lines of in_array, or array_search

Comment: What do you mean by `values`? Is it the sub array which includes `"CategoryId"=>1` or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for a value inside an array:
http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-search.php

```
mixed array_search ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = false ] )
```

Returns the key in the array ($haystack) if the value ($needle) exists.
Returns FALSE if the $needle is not found in the $haystack.